# How to navigate from UIViewController to SplitViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have 6 views.The second controller is Splitviewcontroller and third controller is viewcontroller.Now  How can i navigate from uiviewcontroller which is 3rd view to another splitviewcontroller.

Comment: This isn't enough information. Are they in a UINavigationBar or some other container?
Splitviews only work at the top level....

Answer (score 1):

Your `ViewController` is most likely presented in a modal, in which case it should have a delegate to your `SplitViewController`.

When you're done with the `ViewController`, you can call the protocol method on the delegate, which then dismisses the modal with a call to `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` and voilà, you're back in the `SplitViewController`.

If you're not familiar with the Protocol/Delegate stuff, [here's a good post](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) about it.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your post, can  you edit it with an example that illustrate how to do that? there is no SplitViewController class, there is only master and detail classes. Thanx.